# JavaFX Task Waiting

Tags: java, javafx

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible. But if anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Here is a scenario. I am trying to task A with a progress bar showing the progress, and after task A is completed, I am trying to do task B. Here is the example in code:

```
private void func() {

    // Task A
    class CustomTask extends Task<Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateProgress(i, 4);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Executing Task A
    // CustomProgressBar is a class I made that just binds the progress Property,
    // And the progress bar appears to work.
    CustomTask customTask = new CustomTask();
    CustomProgressBar customProgressBar = new CustomProgressBar(customTask);
    Thread thread = new Thread(customTask);
    thread.start();

    // Task B, For example, just a simple print statement
    System.out.println("After task A is finished");

}
```

In this example, I need Task B to execute after Task A is finished. However, I can not use `thread.join()` because that will block the JavaFX thread, and the progress bar will not update.

Is there a way to accomplish this without putting Task B in `customTask.setOnSucceeded()`?

Comment: What’s wrong with starting the second task from the `onSucceeded` handler of the first task?

Comment: @James_D There is nothing really wrong with it. However, I am trying to write a generic progress bar class. It would be nice if there is a way where the usage of this class can just call the progress bar and continue coding without setting the rest of the code in a `setOnSucceeded` block, but it seems like in one way or another, the task B needs to be in a separate block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onSucceeded` seems one of the most convenient options for doing that. However there are alternatives:

### Run both tasks yourself from a background thread

The following code will always trigger the second task, unless you add in a check. Basically you call `Task.run` on a background thread yourself executing the logic of both threads from that thread. You may need to use `Platform.runLater`, if you want change some bindings when changing tasks.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    firstTask.run();
    secondTask.run();
});
t.start();
```

### Use `ExecutorService`

You could use a single threaded `ExecutorService` to basically do the above.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(firstTask);
executor.submit(secondTask);

...
// Make sure the ececutor is eventually shut down
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The first option wouldn't work for me because JavaFX requires my task B to be on its thread. However, I believe Executor Service seems like a viable solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ChangeListener` to the `state` property of taskA, and if the state changes to `SUCCEEDED`, you can begin taskB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a viable option, but I think this is just similar to `customTask.setOnSucceeded()`